Update SQL column based on the balance carried over from previous rows
I have a table that looks like this:



DocNum
Source
Loc
Bin
Item
Required_SOH
Available_SOH




3
A
ZA
3
ABC
17560
25000


5
A
ZA
3
ABC
5810
NULL


6
A
ZA
3
ABC
3249
NULL


2
B
GB
5
GEF
5000
2000


7
B
GB
5
GEF
200
NULL


8
B
GB
5
GEF
300
NULL



I need to take the Available_SOH from the earliest DocNum and subtract it from the Required_SOH then update the Available_SOH with the balance in the next DocNum that follows. This will be true for each Source, Loc, Bin, Item combination.
So using the example data above, for Source, Loc, Bin, Item combination (A, ZA, 3, ABC), the earliest DocNum is 3 and therefore has an Available_SOH assigned to it. Note all of the earliest DocNums in the table for their respective combination has a SOH value assigned to it that indicates the available stock for that particular item (ABC) in this case.
I need to take the balance of 7440 (Avail_SOH 25000 - Req_SOH 17560) and assign it to Availabe_SOH for DocNum 5 because that's the next DocNum for that combination. Then following the same logic of Avail_SOH 7440 - Req_SOH 5810 = 1630 which will go to Available_SOH for DocNum 6
Therefore the result will look like this:



DocNum
Source
Loc
Bin
Item
Required_SOH
Available_SOH




3
A
ZA
3
ABC
17560
25000


5
A
ZA
3
ABC
5810
7440


6
A
ZA
3
ABC
3249
1630


2
B
GB
5
GEF
5000
2000


7
B
GB
5
GEF
200
-3000


8
B
GB
5
GEF
300
-3200



In short, I need to roll the balance of the stock over to the next DocNum for the Source, Loc, Bin, Item combination. Basically the DocNums that were created first gets the stock fulfilment.
I'm finding it really difficult to articulate what I need but I'm hoping that this makes sense
This is what I tried but It's not giving me the desired result
WITH OrderedData AS (
    SELECT
        DocNum,
        Source,
        Loc,
        Bin,
        Item,
        Required_SOH,
        COALESCE(Available_SOH, 0) AS SOH,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY DocNum) AS RowNum
    FROM #TempSOH
),
CalculatedSOH AS (
    SELECT
        DocNum,
        Source,
        Loc,
        Bin,
        Item,
        Required_SOH,
        Available_SOH,
        SUM(Available_SOH) OVER (PARTITION BY Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY RowNum ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - Required_SOH AS SOH_Calculated
    FROM OrderedData
)
SELECT
    DocNum,
    Source,
    Loc,
    Bin,
    Item,
    Required_SOH,
    CASE
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY DocNum) = 1 THEN SOH_Calculated
        ELSE LAG(SOH_Calculated, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY DocNum)
    END AS SOH
FROM CalculatedSOH
ORDER BY DocNum;


Available value is calculated as difference between
running total for Availible_SOH
and
running total for Ruquired_SOH without current row - because "available" for current row.
See example
select *
  ,sum(Available_SOH)over(partition by Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY DocNum) 
   -sum(Required_SOH)over(partition by Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY DocNum)
   +Required_SOH newAvailable_SOH
from #TempSOH




DocNum
Source
Loc
Bin
Item
Required_SOH
Available_SOH
newAvailable_SOH




3
A
ZA
3
ABC
17560
25000
25000


5
A
ZA
3
ABC
5810
null
7440


6
A
ZA
3
ABC
3249
null
1630


2
B
GB
5
GEF
5000
2000
2000


7
B
GB
5
GEF
200
null
-3000


8
B
GB
5
GEF
300
null
-3200



There expression
  ,sum(Available_SOH)over(partition by Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY DocNum) 
   -sum(Required_SOH)over(partition by Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY DocNum)
   +Required_SOH newAvailable_SOH

is equal
  ,sum(Available_SOH)over(partition by Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY DocNum) 
   -coalesce(sum(Required_SOH)over(partition by Source, Loc, Bin, Item ORDER BY DocNum
                          rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
            ,0)

fiddle

This is exactly what I was looking for! worked like charm, thank you very much!

I haven't tested this but I think this will do what you're asking.
Instead of using window functions I think the best approach to get a running total is to join the table to itself using >= on the DocNum, that will aggregate the previous values that you can then sum to subtract from the current value.
I can see a drawback here if the Available_SOH is ever amended to be lower than the first doc minus combined previous Required_SOH, is that ever the case?
select 
     current.DocNum
    ,current.Source
    ,current.Loc
    ,current.Bin
    ,current.Item
    ,current.Required_SOH
    ,max(history.Available_SOH) - sum(history.Required_SOH) as Available_SOH

from #TempSOH as current
inner join #TempSOH as history on current.Source = history.Source
                        and current.Loc = history.Loc
                        and current.Bin = history.Bin
                        and current.Item = history.Item
                        and current.DocNum >= history.DocNum

group by 
     current.DocNum
    ,current.Source
    ,current.Loc
    ,current.Bin
    ,current.Item
    ,current.Required_SOH
    ,current.Available_SOH

